# haskell type signature for integers

Tags: haskell

Say I want to write a function to decide whether a given integer number is prime, which **type signature** should I use?

```
  isPrime :: Int -> Bool
```

or

```
  isPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
```

What's the difference? Is there a particular reason to choose one over the other?
If so, in which situations should I use the two respectively?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type `Int -> Bool` means that your function operates on values of type `Int`, which are size-limited integers (the maximum size being, I believe, machine-dependent).

The type `(Integral a) => a -> Bool` means that your function operates on values of *any* type that has an instance of the `Integral` type class--i.e., types that *behave like* integers in a particular way. The main reason to chose this over a concrete type is to create a more general-purpose function.

Generic forms using `Integral` tend to be most useful when you need to work with integer-like types in other contexts--a good example being places where the standard library *fails* to do so, e.g. functions like `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`. Code that operates on some specific integer-like type for its own purposes that wants to use that type with `replicate` therefore needs to convert to `Int` first, or import `genericReplicate` from `Data.List`.

What you might want to consider in your case is instead the type `Integer`, which represents integers of arbitrary size. Since your main goal is the calculation, there's less value to supporting arbitrary integral types.

If memory serves me, the only instances of `Integral` in the standard library are `Int` and `Integer` anyhow. (**EDIT**: As hammar reminds me in the comments, there are also instances for fixed-size types in `Data.Int` and `Data.Word`. There are also foreign types like `CInt` but I was disregarding those intentionally.)

Comment: There are also the fixed-size ones in `Data.Int` and `Data.Word`.

Comment: @hammar: Ah, right! I forgot those were actually part of the standard libraries, thanks.

Comment: Third option: define a typeclass `class HasPrimes a where isPrime :: a -> Bool` would let you define a different primality algorithm for each type.  You could even define a default `instance Integral a => HasPrimes a where ...` with a general purpose algorithm.  The advantage here is that if you had a more efficient algorithm for a particular type, you could also use that, so it'd be the best of both worlds.

Comment: @rampion The default instance is IMO a bad idea, as that would necessitate `OverlappingInstances`. The class is a good idea.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I suppose `instance HasPrimes Integer` and `isIntegralPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool ; isIntegralPrime = isPrime . toInteger` would suffice rather than a default instance.

Comment: @rampion Yes, I think that would do fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Or, if you wanted to restrict `HasPrimes` to `Integral` types, you could use a default implementation in the class itself: `class Integral a => HasPrimes a where isPrime :: a -> Bool ; isPrime = isIntegerPrime . toInteger`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the signature

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
```

A signature `isPrime :: Int -> Bool` would exclude fast tests for largish numbers, since those tests would often overflow then (technically that is also true of `Integer`, at least in the version provided by `integer-gmp`, but you will most likely be out of memory *long* before that matters, so we can maintain the fiction of an infinite `Integer` type).

A type `isPrime :: Integral a => a -> Bool` would be a lie with any feasible implementation. One could have an instance of `Integral` for a type modeling `Z[sqrt(2)]` (though for such a type `toInteger` would be unfaithful), for such a type, 2 would not be a prime, how would one detect that with a generic test?

Or consider finite types modeling a factor ring `Z/(n)`. An `Ord` instance for such types would be incompatible with the arithmetic, but we already have that for `Int` etc. For example, in `Z(6) = {0,1,2,3,4,5}`, the [primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) would be 2, 3 and 4 (note that none of them is [irreducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element), 2 = 4*2, 3 = 3*3, 4 = 2*2).

So the only meaningful and feasible test is, "is it a rational (or natural) prime whose value happens to be in the range of the type?". That is captured (as good as possible without sacrificing too much speed) in the type `isPrime :: Integer -> Bool`, to be combined with a `toInteger` when appropriate.

Comment: this is not about my question but why isn't 5 a prime since 5 is non-zero non-unit and `5 | 1*5 => 5 | 5`; also why 2 and 3 are not irreducible

Comment: 5 is a unit, `5*5 = 1`. And we can write `2 = 4*2`, neither 4 nor 2 being a unit, and `3 = 3*3`, neither 3 nor 3 being a unit, so 2 and 3 are reducible. On the other hand, if 2 divides `a*b` then 2 must already divide `a` or `b` (that is inherited from Z), so 2 is a prime (alternatively, `(Z/6)/2 ~ Z/3`, the factor ring of `Z/(6)` by the ideal generated by 2 is the field `Z/(3)`, in particular an integral domain). Similar for 3.

Comment: I think I'd better turn to a book on abstract algebra rather than bothering you with basic concepts here; so you think we can't deal with such stuff with Haskell or with any other programming languages?

Comment: Oh, those concepts aren't so basic. But a good book is certainly a better way to learn it - if you want to - than the limited space in SO comments. Dealing with such stuff correctly isn't trivial, the `Integral` class is not the right way for it, but rampion proposed a `HasPrimes` class in the comments for C.A. McCann's answer, then each instance would be responsible for the correct behaviour in that case. Note that primes in rings with zero divisors like `Z/(6)` are not very interesting. But the other example or polynomial rings are interesting and don't fit in the `Integral` corset.

Answer (score 1):

Many primality tests are probabilistic and need random numbers, so at least at the lowest level they would have a type signature like this:

```
seemsPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

An Integral constraint seems reasonable, because usually you do not need a concrete type, but only operations like `rem`.

Comment: Well, a probabilistic test would need a monadic return type: `seemsPrime :: (Integral a) => a -> [a] -> IO Bool`